# Can any element of a group generate a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Given a Group G, can we choose any non-identity element and say that this element will be the generator of a cyclic group contained in G ?

Comment: Yes, if this element has finite order.

Comment: @Bernard ah okay , Good It clears up some confusion I had when studying a proof on prime order groups, Thank you :)

Comment: @Bernard Why “finite order”?

Comment: It's Bourbaki's convention, I believe: infinite groups generated by a single element are called `monogenous`. At least that's the way I learnt it (long ago…).

Comment: The group generated from a single element can only be either cyclic or infinite.

Comment: It is common to define "cyclic group" to mean _any_ group generated by a single element. Such a group is always isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/\langle n\rangle$ for some $n$, if it is finite, or to $\mathbb Z$ if it is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No only we can say it as furthermore it is indeed true. If $g\in G$, $\langle g\rangle$ is always a cyclic group (and a subgroup of $G$, of course).